# Проблема с углами в круглой кнопки

Tags: android, android-drawable

У меня есть `ListView`, а в  элементе  списка есть  круглая кнопка.

Делал ее круглой так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/task_list_parent_indicator"
                android:width="@dimen/task_list_parent_indicator"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                />
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/tool_bar_button_radius"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Выглядит она круглой, но при нажатии на элемент видно квадрат кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать, чтоб кнопка даже при нажатии на элемент оставалась круглой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/task_list_parent_indicator"
                android:width="@dimen/task_list_parent_indicator"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                />
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/tool_bar_button_radius"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/task_list_parent_indicator"
            android:width="@dimen/task_list_parent_indicator"
            />
        <solid
            android:color="#любой другой цвет"
            />
        <corners
            android:radius="@dimen/tool_bar_button_radius"
            />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.1dp"
            android:color="@color/colorAccent"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Но лучше разделять логику состояния\рисунок